# vector of vector with different types

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, boost, stl

I would like to construct a vector of vectors. This question has already been posted many time on SO but I did not find a satisfying answer. That because:

- each vector can have a different type
- I don't know the types at compilation time
- I don't know how many vectors it will contain

Basically I would like to be able to do something like that in pseudo code
later

```
types = ["char", "int", "double", "int"]
container<vector> x

foreach (type in types)
{
  if (type == "char")
    x.push_back(vector<char>)
  else if (type == "int")
    x.push_back(vector<int>)
  else
    x.push_back(vector<double>)
}
```

and then I would like to be able to do for example

```
x[0].push_back("a")
x[1].push_back(1)
x[2].push_back(3.1416)
```

I think `boost::any` may help me but I'm not familiar with boost yet.

The point is, even if it sound weird, it is really what I want to do. I don't want a vector of structures, I really want a container (no matter which one) containing `std::vector` of different types. The reason is because I'm reading binary files. The header of the file states the number of data and their types but it can change from a file to another. Thus it cannot be known at compilation time.

Comment: How should the **statically typed** language resolve `x[i].push_back(...);` when `i` is not a compile time constant expression?

Comment: use `boost/std::variant`

Comment: @geza: A variant won't help if OP doesn't know the types at compilation time. `any` would be better, but this smells of a design flaw.

Comment: @AndyG: I think he knows the possible types, he just don't know a given vector's type.

Comment: @AndyG yet it smell of a design error. That is why I'm embarrassed with this question...

Comment: Vector is essentially an implementation of dynamic-size array. All array elements must have the same type.

Comment: @JRR: If geza is right and you know the possible types it can take on, there's no shame in using a variant with a visitor pattern.

Comment: @JRR: if binary file could contain different types, so the `vector<variant<vector<char>, vector<int>, ...>>` solution mirrors the binary structure, then there's nothing wrong with this, I don't think it's a design error.

Comment: @gaza could you show me an example? Even with pseudo code. It sounds good but I'm not comfortable with this tiny piece of code out of context

Comment: @JRR: look at jbcoe's answer, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I edited my post. I looking for an `std::something` of `std::vector`. `somthing` is not necessarily a vector

Comment: Please update your pseudo code to reflect that `std::vector` is not the only container you use. It's hard to follow what's going on now...

Comment: Do you have samples of inputs? I'm curious to maybe try something

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you could use a vector of variants?

```
using ints = std::vector<int>;
using chars = std::vector<char>;
using doubles = std::vector<double>;
using mixed_data_t = std::vector<std::variant<chars, ints, doubles>>;
```

If each file has the same type of data you can find out what it is at run time and push back into the appropriate variant-vector.

If the files have mixed data then you could use

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<char, int, double>>>;
```

but you will have to check on each insertion.

I'm fairly confident that `boost::any` is not the solution you are looking for as type information will be lost after each insertion.

Comment: The point is that the file is standardized but can have extra data that are free. The header clearly states what it contains but at compilation time I don't know. Only once I read the header.

Comment: @JRR the type of the variant is decided at runtime. The runtime type can vary between the types sent as template parameter.

Comment: Make sure you have `c++17` support.

Comment: Is there a boost equivalent that do not require c++17 ?

Comment: @PhotometricStereo: Unfortunately the question is tagged C++11, so OP is stuck implementing their own variant or using boost's implementation.

Comment: @JRR: Like geza said on the OP it's called `boost::variant`

Comment: One could use boost::variant or eggs::variant.

Comment: @AndyG That's why I mentioned it. The answer clearly has a `c++17` solution so I wanted to point that out.

Comment: Well I can switch to c++17 but if I can continue in c++11 it is better.

Comment: I will explore this solution with `boost`. Sounds to be good. I will give you some news once I will had coded that stuff.